# How do I make a character handle an object?

Tags: animation, objects

How do I get a human character to manipulate an object without having to go frame by frame or joint by joint + frame by frame?

The reason I ask is because it's incredibly difficult and time consuming having to account for each individual joint through various frames. I would like to know if there is a simple way to have a human character grab a weapon and use it similar to how any real human would use an object.

Comment: You can add 2 loose extra bones in your rig somewhere on each palm. Later you can attach any object to these new bones by adding a "Child of" constraint on the object. Then you can key-frame object's influence from 0 to 1 when you want your character to hold and drop the object.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to add extra bones  can you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: There are so many basic armature tutorials on youtube I honestly don't even know which to recommend since they are all good. But simply put, 
1. Place the 3d cursor on the palm by clicking shift+RMB
2. Go to edit mode for your rig and hit shift+A to add a new bone.
3. Scale and rotate the new bone
4. Name it like hand_item_l if the new bone in the left palm, _r otherwise.
5. Open "Find" menu and hit symmetrize to place the same bone in the other palm.
Now you can use that bone as a target in carried object's "child of" constraint